# Segfault when using fscanf

Tags: c, file-io, scanf

I am currently trying to read multiple floats from a file. When I use just one variable it works fine, but there are issues when saving to multiple floats:

```
float r_testdata[3276334];
float i_testdata[3276334];
int e = 1;

FILE *fpI_i = fopen("/home/users/Documents/document.dat","r");

for(int i = 0; i < 3276334;i++) {
    e = fscanf(fpI_i,"%f %f",&r_testdata[i],&i_testdata[i]);
    if(e != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error reading file\n");
    }

}
fclose(fpI_i);
```

When fscans runs with 2 reads it segfaults. It seems like a formatting issue with fscanf, but I am failing to see what the issue is. I have looked at posts with similar issues and it has not been fixed.

Comment: Is this all in the same function? We can't tell [because your code is not a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If it is, then `float real_testdata[3276334];` is (part of?) the problem --- between the two structures, you're allocating 24MB of data *on the stack*.

Comment: `e != 1` --> `e != 2` and typo variable name.

Comment: If you just need to scan floating-point numbers, I'd recommend you using `double` and, thereafter `%lf`

Comment: Please choose a language, either `C` or `C++`.  They are not the same thing.  Depending on the language, you can get differing answers.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY - why not post that as an answer?

Comment: @4386427 The issue could be the stack being blown out, as pointed out by Tim Cas.

Comment: @RadLexus - I didn't see the segfault as it was only mentioned in the title. My fault.

Comment: Does the problem magically disappear if you use `malloc` for those huge arrays?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Size was a concern to me. So stack size seems to be what the issue may be?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I chose C and C++ as tags because I am compiling with C++, but I use C syntax mostly so either fix will be fine.

Comment: @Rad Lexus I only have slight experience with malloc, but will that allow me to create the amount of space I need?

Comment: @lynder  If it's C++, then `std::vector<float> r_testData(3276334), l_testData(3276334);` works without resorting to `malloc`.  So now you see why it's important that you actually decide on the language -- there is no such thing as `std::vector` in `C`.

Comment: @RadLexus Malloc fixed this issue. Was definitely the size. Will accept as answer if you post

Comment: Nah, @4386427 pretty much nailed it :) No need for repeats.

Comment: @PaulMckenzie Thanks, used std::vector as well in place of malloc as a sanity check and it worked, definitely more elegant fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems likely you have a stack overflow due to huge arrays. If they are inside a function like:

```
void foo(void)
{
    float r_testdata[3276334];
    float i_testdata[3276334];
```

the stack is too small to hold them and that result in memory corruption and a segfault.

You can make them global like:

```
float r_testdata[3276334];  // Declared outside the function
float i_testdata[3276334];

void foo(void)
{
```

or better use dynamic memory allocation using `malloc`. Like:

```
float *r_testdata = malloc(3276334 * sizeof(float));
```

and when your done with `r_testdata` remember to call `free(r_testdata);`

As mentioned by @BLUEPIXY:

This line is wrong:

```
if(e != 1) {
```

You are trying to read two values so you must use:

```
if(e != 2) {
```

Comment: This did actually fix the next issue I would've had thanks. edit: Also addressed my size issue, this fixed, malloc allocated the memory I needed. Higher level languages with Python and Matlab has me spoiled :p